# Android: Quickblox use back camera for capture image while video chat

Tags: android, android-camera, quickblox, quickblox-android

I use below code but after click, localview visibility have gone

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way you can use a camera intent and keep your app working with camera at the same time. Actually, it's not guaranteed that a single app can use both cameras in parallel, but in some devices, e..g. based on Snapdragon 820 chipset, it simply works.